# AngularJS - Remove/Add Class on element based off if element is active/hover/or contains a value

Tags: html, jquery, angularjs

I have a magnifying glass that when you hover or click on it, it expands to a full search bar. I want the functionality to be that when the search bar is active, it will stay expanded until clicked off, or will stay expanded if the bar has a value. I have the logic in jQuery, but this is my first time using AngularJS (not Angular) and I do not know how to turn this jQuery into a directive, or if there is some built in functionality I am missing. Thank you!

```
jQuery("#inpt_search").on("focus", function () {
 jQuery(this).parent("label").addClass("active");
});

jQuery("#inpt_search").on("blur", function () {
 if (jQuery(this).val().length == 0)
   jQuery(this).parent("label").removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
// set for Home Controller
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.blueClass = function() {
      $scope.class_name = "blue";
      $scope.multi_message ="Blue Class Added";
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

      <div class="alert" ng-class="{blue:'bg-info', red:'bg-danger',green:'bg-success' }[class_name]">{{multi_message}}</div>

      <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="blueClass()"> Blue Class</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask